# java programming giving "symbol error"

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class pyth{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("enter n");
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=in.nextInt();
        {
            for(int a=1;a>n;a++) {
                for(int b=a+1;b>n;b++) {
                    int c=n-a-b ;
                }
                if(c*c=a*a+b*b) {
                    System.out.println(a+','+b+','+c+',');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to programming, so I can't really figure out the problem. This is the error:

> pyth.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
> if(c*c=a*a+b*b)
>
> ^ symbol:   variable c
>
> location: class pyth

Comment: You are using `c` out of its scope. Maybe move the `if` inside the `for`.

Comment: `c` isn't accessible out of the `for loop` above your `if` statement; you're using the assignment `=` in your `if` statement, when you should be using the `==`, since it compares; You have two infinite loops: both of your `for` statement, which is `while a is greater than n increment a` and the same with `b`.

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly, syntax is very important. Maintain indents. Makes the code easier to read and understand and also helps in maintenance.**

The errors in your code :

1. `int c=n-a-b ;` c is being used in the if comparison. So needs to be declared beforehand. Similarly, `int b` also has to be declared before hand for use in the if statement.
2. if(c*c=a*a+b*b)    `=` is an assignment operator. Use `==` to make comparisons. And use more brackets to get rid of ambiguity.

Additionally :

System.out.println(a+','+b+','+c+','); this isnt a mistake as such, but its better to use `","`.

**This should workd :**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class pyth{
    public static void main(String[] args){
         System.out.println("enter n");
         Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
         int b,c;
         int n=in.nextInt();

         for(int a=1;a>n;a++) {
             for(b=a+1;b>n;b++)  {
                 c=n-a-b ;
             }

             if(c*c==(a*a+b*b)) {
                 System.out.println(a+","+b+","+c+",");
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't change **ONE** character and not even bother pointing out **WHAT** you changed.

Comment: thanx,,,but it still shows    error: variable declaration not allowed here
        int c=n-a-b ;}

Comment: because you wrote int c again inside the for loop. This code will work. I have updated it. And syntax is important. maintain indents and proper brackets. :)

Comment: but in your prgm you havent declare c anywhere??

Comment: @MarcB I just posted the solution first to help him as fast as possible, then I edited and made my answer better by adding all the information. That is the method I always follow. :)

Comment: It was my mistake. I fixed it. this is the updated code. When we declare c before the for loop, both the for loop and the if statement will be able to access c. Hence it is declared outside. :)

Comment: And if this is the solution you were looking for, please do mark the answer as accepted. Helps me gain reputation and future users to get the best answer easily. Thank You. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
            if(c*c=a*a+b*b) {
                  ^--- assignment
```

You cannot assign the result of one expression to another expression. It should be `==`

Answer (score 0):

ok, the issue of your compilation errors is scoping of variables.

you defined int c = n-a-b inside a for block and it is not accessible outside that block.

similarly the variable b is not accessible outside the block

```
 for (int b = a + 1; b > n; b++) {
    c = n - a - b;
 }
```

as it's scope ends at the end of loop.

Also where you are checking for equality, you should use == instead of = , which is for assignment.

I am not sure what you want to do through your code,  but the code should be something as follows :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class pyth {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("enter n");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int c = 0, a=0, b=0;

        for (a = 1; a > n; a++) {
            for (b = a + 1; b > n; b++) {
                c = n - a - b;
            }
            if ((c * c) == (a * a) + (b * b))
                System.out.println(a + ',' + b + ',' + c + ',');
        }
    }
}
```